# Bug on Keras fit_generator, running few steps more than it should

Tags: python, keras, generator, yield

I found `fit_generator()` would run few steps more than it should.
I set `steps_per_epoch=100`. i and k both start from 0. But at the end of training process, it will print out `k = 109`. This situation only occurs when validation data are added.

```
def data_generate(xfd, yfd, x_line_offset, y_line_offset):

    while True:
        k = 0

        x_line_offset, y_line_offset = shuffle_list(x_line_offset, y_line_offset)

        for i in range(100):
            print('i = {}'.format(i))
            print('k = {}'.format(k))
            k += 1

            x_train = get_line_by_offset(xfd, x_line_offset[i])
            x_train = rescaling(x_train, 0, 65535, 0, 1)
            y_train = get_line_by_offset(yfd, y_line_offset[i])

            yield x_train, y_train

train_generator = data_generate(xfd_train, yfd_train, x_train_line_offset, y_train_line_offset)
validation_generator = data_generate(xfd_valid, yfd_valid, x_valid_line_offset, y_valid_line_offset)

model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=100,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=len(fix_y_valid_line_offset), epochs=1)
```

Since it will print out `k = 109`, I assume it runs few more steps. I don't know if it's bug or not. But the keras log message doesn't show after `k = 99`.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No bugs here, it's just some implementation details. The function `fit_generator()` has a default argument `max_queue_size=10`. The batches from `train_generator` and `validation_generator` will be inserted into queues before getting used to fit/evaluate the model.

When the first epoch ends, there are 100 batches generated (`k = 99`). However, the generator will continue to generate 10 batches to fill up the queue. That's why you're seeing `k = 100` to `k = 109`. At the same time, the validation process begins, so you'll also see `k = 0, ...` coming from the `validation_generator`.