# Keras fit_generator: Unexpected usage of __getitem__ method

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am using the fit_generator function to train my models and want to verify that my data is constructed and used as intended. My class derived from keras.utils.Sequence() implements the methods `__getitem__`, `__len__` and `on_epoch_end` and looks like this:

```
class PairwiseSequence(Sequence):
"""Generator that returns a combination of simulations (over a
parametrizable amount of timesteps) and the corresponding metric distance.

pair_list: List of pairwise combinations of simulations
results: dictionary with results for the metric distance between
         simulation pairs
sim_files: List of filenames representing single timesteps
batch_size: number of samples to process in a single interference run
"""

def __init__(self, pair_list, results, mean, std, train=False, sim_files=None,
             batch_size=1):
    self.pair_list = pair_list
    self.results = results
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.sim_files = sim_files
    self.mean = mean
    self.std = std
    self.train = train

def __len__(self):
    return math.ceil(len(self.pair_list) / self.batch_size)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    dummy = LOADING_METHOD(self.pair_list[0][0], self.sim_files)
    x_1 = np.zeros(tuple([self.batch_size]) + dummy.shape)
    x_2 = np.zeros(tuple([self.batch_size]) + dummy.shape)
    y = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1))

    if self.train:
        #print((idx * self.batch_size + i) % len(self.pair_list), ',')
        print("training idx:", idx)
    else:
        print("validation idx:", idx)

        for i in range(0, self.batch_size):
        (sim1, sim2) = self.pair_list[(idx * self.batch_size + i) %
                                      len(self.pair_list)]
        x_1[i] = LOADING_METHOD(sim1, self.sim_files) - self.mean[0]
        x_1[i] /= self.std[0]
        x_2[i] = LOADING_METHOD(sim2, self.sim_files) - self.mean[1]
        x_2[i] /= self.std[1]
        y[i] = self.results[frozenset((sim1.ensemble, sim2.ensemble))]
    return [x_1, x_2], y

def on_epoch_end(self):
    if self.train:
        print("training generator: epoch end")
    else:
        print("validation generator: epoch end")
    #random.shuffle(self.pair_list)
```

This class is used as generator for training and validation data (two separate instances).

As you can see I am printing the `idx` parameter of `__getitem__` and some notifcation when an epoch ends to the console. I am invoking fit_generator as followed (with turned of multiprocessing):

```
history_callback = model.fit_generator(
    generator=train_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_gen),
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=0,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_data=valid_gen,
    validation_steps=len(valid_gen),
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    shuffle=False
)
```

Also I turned of shuffling of the data. With this configuration I would have expected that `idx` goes from 0 to len(generator) and after that `on_epoch_end` is invoked. I have 372 samples for training and 93 for validation with batch_size 12 `idx` should go from 0 to 30 (training data) respectively 0 to 7 (validation data). But `__getitem__` gets invoked more often than I expected and also `on_epoch_end` gets called inbetween! Here is how the console output looks like:

```
batch_size: 12
len(train_gen): 31
len(valid_gen): 8
2018-02-14 08:45:09.041929: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
training idx: 0
training idx: 1
training idx: 2
training idx: 3
training idx: 4
training idx: 5
training idx: 6
training idx: 7
training idx: 8
training idx: 9
training idx: 10
training idx: 11
training idx: 12
training idx: 13
training idx: 14
training idx: 15
training idx: 16
training idx: 17
training idx: 18
training idx: 19
training idx: 20
training generator: epoch end
training idx: 21
training idx: 22
training idx: 23
training idx: 24
training idx: 25
training idx: 26
training idx: 27
training idx: 28
training idx: 29
training idx: 30
training idx: 0
validation generator: epoch end
validation idx: 0
training idx: 1
validation idx: 1
training idx: 2
validation idx: 2
training idx: 3
validation idx: 3
training idx: 4
validation idx: 4
training idx: 5
validation idx: 5
validation generator: epoch end
training idx: 6
validation idx: 6
training idx: 7
validation idx: 7
training idx: 8
validation idx: 0
training idx: 9
validation idx: 1
training idx: 10
validation idx: 2
validation idx: 3
validation idx: 4
validation idx: 5
validation idx: 6
validation idx: 7
validation idx: 0
validation idx: 1
validation idx: 2
Epoch 00000: val_loss improved from inf to 10512.69922, saving model to /home/stefan/vcs/MA/code/results/test/TB_dummy_distance_10513.hdf5
training idx: 11
training idx: 12
training idx: 13
training idx: 14
training idx: 15
training idx: 16
training idx: 17
training idx: 18
training idx: 19
training idx: 20
training generator: epoch end
training idx: 21
training idx: 22
training idx: 23
training idx: 24
training idx: 25
training idx: 26
training idx: 27
training idx: 28
training idx: 29
training idx: 30
training idx: 0
validation generator: epoch end
validation idx: 0
training idx: 1
validation idx: 1
training idx: 2
validation idx: 2
training idx: 3
validation idx: 3
training idx: 4
validation idx: 4
training idx: 5
validation idx: 5
validation generator: epoch end
training idx: 6
validation idx: 6
training idx: 7
validation idx: 7
validation idx: 0
training idx: 8
validation idx: 1
training idx: 9
validation idx: 2
training idx: 10
validation idx: 3
validation idx: 4
validation idx: 5
validation idx: 6
validation idx: 7
validation idx: 0
validation idx: 1
validation idx: 2
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from 10512.69922 to 5905.95929, saving model to /home/stefan/vcs/MA/code/results/test/TB_dummy_distance_5906.hdf5
```

How does fit_generator use the `__getitem__` and `on_epoch_end` methods? Does it also call these methods to get some sample data for weight initialization before the first epoch starts? Is this behaviour caused by some kind of caching?

Any help is appreciated very much! Thank you in advance!

## Update:

For testing purposes I changed the `max_queue_size` argument of `fit_generator` to 1. This is the resulting terminal output:

```
batch_size: 12
len(train_gen): 31
len(valid_gen): 8
2018-02-14 10:10:40.001065: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
training idx: 0
training idx: 1
training idx: 2
training idx: 3
training idx: 4
training idx: 5
training idx: 6
training idx: 7
training idx: 8
training idx: 9
training idx: 10
training idx: 11
training idx: 12
training idx: 13
training idx: 14
training idx: 15
training idx: 16
training idx: 17
training idx: 18
training idx: 19
training idx: 20
training idx: 21
training idx: 22
training idx: 23
training idx: 24
training idx: 25
training idx: 26
training idx: 27
training idx: 28
training idx: 29
training idx: 30
training generator: epoch end
training idx: 0
training idx: 1
validation idx: 0
validation idx: 1
validation idx: 2
validation idx: 3
validation idx: 4
validation idx: 5
validation idx: 6
validation generator: epoch end
validation idx: 7
validation idx: 0
validation idx: 1
Epoch 00000: val_loss improved from inf to 18090.34473, saving model to /home/stefan/vcs/MA/code/results/test/TB_dummy_distance_18090.hdf5
training idx: 2
training idx: 3
training idx: 4
training idx: 5
training idx: 6
training idx: 7
training idx: 8
training idx: 9
training idx: 10
training idx: 11
training idx: 12
training idx: 13
training idx: 14
training idx: 15
training idx: 16
training idx: 17
training idx: 18
training idx: 19
training idx: 20
training idx: 21
training idx: 22
training idx: 23
training idx: 24
training idx: 25
training idx: 26
training idx: 27
training idx: 28
training idx: 29
training idx: 30
training generator: epoch end
training idx: 0
training idx: 1
validation idx: 0
validation idx: 1
validation idx: 2
validation idx: 3
validation idx: 4
validation idx: 5
validation idx: 6
validation generator: epoch end
validation idx: 7
validation idx: 0
validation idx: 1
Epoch 00001: val_loss did not improve
```

Now at least in the very first epoch all training samples get queried. But for the validation data and training data in the second epoch, `on_epoch_end` still gets called to early.

Comment: The question about extra batches is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46233385/1531463).

Comment: Why asking here when you can just read the code ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I tried to understand the behaviour by reading the code of fit_generator from [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py) `keras/engine/training.py` but I did not find where `on_epoch_end` of the generator gets called.

Comment: @Yu-Yang: Thank you for that comment and the link! Do you also know what could be the cause that `on_epoch_end` gets called inbetween (to early?!) ?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. `on_epoch_end` always appears at the right place on my machine. What's your platform and which version of Keras do you use?

Comment: Does the problem remain if you add `flush=True` to the `print` functions?

Comment: @Yu-Yang: I am using keras from tensorflow.python.keras with Tensorflow 1.4.0. I Just tried it on another machine using the same Tensorflow version, on that machine `on_epoch_end` also appears at the right place, using flush=True also fixed the output on my first machine! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work for you

```
def gen(train_data):
    print('generator initiated')
    #Define a batch size
    batch_size = 64

    #Complete length of data
    data_size = len(train_data)

    #Total number of batches will be created
    num_batches = int(data_size / batch_size)


    if (num_batches*batch_size) < data_size:
         num_batches += 1
    while True:
        cnt=0
        for i in range(num_batches):
            start_index = cnt * batch_size
            end_index = min((cnt + 1) * batch_size, data_size)
            cnt +=1

            //Do some preprocessing 
            x_train_padded = add_pad(x_train,3,pad)
            x_train_padded = np.array(x_train_padded)

            yield (x_train_padded,y_train_padded)


fun_model.fit_generator(gen(train_data),steps_per_epoch =int(len(train_data)/64),nb_epoch=50,callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=2,shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have to use a keras.Sequence() instance instead of a normal generator to avoid duplicated data when using multiprocessing. I only deactivated multiprocessing for debugging purposes. Also this does not explain why `__getitem__` is called that often (and `on_epoch_end` inbetween).